# how to add a div only after submitting my form after validation?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have created a registration form with jQuery validation plugin, I want to add a div element to the page only after the user clicks on submit after validation. But the div gets added along with the validation messages if I click on it before filling the form, can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong here?

**custregister.js**

```
$(function(){
    
    $("#register").validate({
          errorElement: 'div',
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            if(element.parent('.input-group').length) {
                error.insertAfter(element.parent());
            } else {
                error.insertAfter(element);
            }
        },
        rules:{
            first_name:{
                required:true,
                minlength:3
            },
            last_name:{
                required:true,
                minlength:3
            },
            user_name:{
                required:true,
                minlength:5,
            },
            user_password:{
                required:true,
                minlength:5
            },
            confirm_password:{
                required:true,
                equalTo:"#password"
            },
            email:{
                required:true,
                email:true
            },
            contact_no:{
                required:true,
                phone_no:true
            },
        },
        messages:{
            first_name:{
                required:"Please enter your firstname",
                minlength:"Invalid name"
            },
            last_name:{
                required:"Please enter your firstname",
                minlength:"Invalid name"
            },
            user_name:{
                required:"Please enter a username",
                minlength:"Your usernmae must contains atleast 5 characters"
            },
            user_password:{
                required:"Please provide a password",
                minlength: "Your password must be atleast 5 characters long"
            },
            confirm_password:{
                required:"Please provide a password",
                equalTo:"Passwords do not match, enter correct password"
            },
            email:{
                required:"Please enter your email",
                email:"Please enter a valid email"
            },
            contact_no:{
                required:"Enter your phone number"
            },
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
          form.submit();
        }
    });
    var newDiv = $('<div class="col-md-6"><h4><a>Registered</a></h4> </div>');
    //newDiv.style.background = "#000";
     $('body').append(newDiv);
});

jQuery.validator.addMethod("phone_no",function(value, element){
    return this.optional(element) || /^[6-9]\d{9}$/.test(value);
},"This Phone number is not valid");
```

**custregister.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Customer Registration Form</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Langar&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<link rel = "stylesheet" href = custregister.css >

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
     <form name="registration" class="well form-horizontal" method = "post" action = "#"  id="register">
        <fieldset>

<!-- Form Name -->
<legend><center><h1><b>Registration Form</b></h1></center></legend><br>

<!-- Text input-->

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">First Name</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
  <div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
  <input  name="first_name" id="firstname" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control"  type="text" >
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" >Last Name</label> 
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
  <input name="last_name" id="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control"  type="text" >
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  
<!-- Text input-->

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Username</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
  <div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
  <input  name="user_name" id="username" placeholder="Username" class="form-control"  type="text" >
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" >Password</label> 
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
  <input name="user_password" id="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control"  type="password" >
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" >Confirm Password</label> 
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
  <input name="confirm_password" id="confirm_password" placeholder="Confirm Password" class="form-control"  type="password" >
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
       <div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail</label>  
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span>
  <input name="email" id="email" placeholder="E-Mail Address" class="form-control"  type="email" >
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- Text input-->
       
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Contact No.</label>  
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></i></span>
  <input name="contact_no" id="phone" placeholder="(+91)" class="form-control" type="text" >
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Select Basic -->

<!-- Button -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label"></label>
  <div class="col-md-4"><br>
    <button id="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" >SUBMIT <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></button>
  <!--  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" formaction = "CustLogin.html">LOGIN <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></button> -->
  </div>
</div>

</fieldset>
</form>
</div>
    </div><!-- /.container -->
    
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="custregister.js"></script>     
    <script src="admin_cust_status.js"></script>            
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Did you tried to put `var newDiv = [...]` just after `form.submit();` ?

Comment: Yes, I tried but it didn't work for me. The problem is that whenever I click on submit, div is added in both the cases, first when the form is filled and other case in which form has invalid data or not filled. In the second case, div gets added along with displaying the validation messages.